# jQuery Nice Select not working with overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using [hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select](https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/) plugin and trying to make it truncate long named option strings.

Select is not working properly when overflow is set to hidden - when clicked dropdown not appears. (it appears but not shown and you can still choose option by up/down arrows) 
I just want to hide too long strings with ellipsis nicely. Is there any way to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Here is an [example on codepen](https://codepen.io/Dmitrevicz/pen/RwwQgwg).

```
<select class="bug-overflow">
  <option value="First one">Bug First lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem one</option>
  <option value="Second One">Bug Second lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem one</option>
</select>

/* bug style */
.bug-overflow {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden; /*bug here*/
  white-space: nowrap;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').niceSelect();
});
```

Checked on mac os 10.13.6 (chrome, opera, safari), windows 10 (chrome, opera, ff), android (chrome, samsung internet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.
I apologize to those who managed to spend their time reading my problem. But I have already found a way to solve it. (I just was inattentive applying styles to wrong element)

```
/*found solution*/
/*override .current for my purposes*/
.custom-style .current {
  width: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

<select class="custom-style">
  <option value="First one">Bug First lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem one</option>
  <option value="Second One">Bug Second lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem one</option>
</select>
```